# checkbox state wont persist on form submit

Tags: php, forms

I have a series of checkboxes, when the form submits and there is an error (via jquery validation), I need the state of those checkboxes to persist obviously so they don't have to be re-entered:

```
<fieldset class="group">
        <label for="s_type" class="mandatory full-width <?=$errors['s_type']?>"><strong>Please indicate which you are applying for:</strong></label>
        <span class="clear"></span>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="group">
        <div class="field">
            <input <?php if($s_type == "Fund Scholarship") { echo 'checked';} ?> type="checkbox" value="Fund Scholarship" name="s_type[]" id="s_type_fund" validate="required:true">
            <label>Fund Scholarship</label><br/>
            <input <?php if($s_type == "Foundation Scholarship") { echo 'checked';} ?> type="checkbox" value="Foundation Scholarship" name="s_type[]" id="s_type_foundation">
            <label>Foundation Scholarship</label><br />
            <input <?php if($s_type == "Memorial Scholarship") { echo 'checked';} ?> type="checkbox" value="Memorial Scholarship" name="s_type[]" id="s_type_mem">
            <label>Memorial Scholarship</label><br />
            <label class="error" for="s_type[]">This field is required</label></div>
    </fieldset>
```

For some reason, its only saving when I've selected ONE of the options, if I select 2 or 3, it does not save? Not sure what i'm missing

Edit: oh I should mention that when more than one is selected, it just loses all the states, even though when I select one, it keeps that correctly.

Edit: I just realised that at the top of the code the following:

```
$s_type = implode("; ", $_POST['s_type']);
```

I assume thats why $s_type=="Fund Scholarship" supposedly works in another php page i'm using to model this one

Comment: lol another downvote for wot ??

Answer (score 0):

`$s_type` can only ever equal one thing at a time.

If you want to use all of them try [in_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

```
<input <?php if(in_array("Foundation Scholarship",$_REQUEST['s_type'])) echo 'checked'; ?> type="checkbox" value="Foundation Scholarship" name="s_type[]" id="s_type_foundation">
```

Comment: thx but that gave me:   Warning: in_array() [function.in-array]: Wrong datatype for second argument in /scholarships/business-form.php on line 458
type="checkbox" value="Fund Scholarship" name="s_type[]" id="s_type_fund" validate="required:true"> Fund Scholarship...

and the checkboxes are all messed up